# How to aggregate row values with multiple row criteria

Tags: r

I'm trying to aggregate values present in rows in which repeated values present in other columns must be used as a criteria:

This is what I have:

```
Candidate, City, Ballot Box Number, Number of Votes

   A Halifax 1 100

   A Halifax 2 100

   A Halifax 3 100

   A Glasgow 4 100

   B Halifax 1 100

   B Halifax 2 0

   B Halifax 3 50

   B Glasgow 4 3
```

This is what I want:

```
Candidate,City,Number of Votes
   
   A,Halifax,300

   A,Glasgow,100

   B,Halifax,150

   B,Glasgow,3
```

It's similar to Dynamic Table functions in Excel. I need to make partial aggregations to extract useful information from this dataset.

Already tried `aggregate` and `rowsums` functions, but wasn't able to insert multiple conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time, please make it easy to reproduce your example data. Use this code:

```
library(tidyverse)

candidate <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
city <- c("Halifax", "Halifax", "Halifax", "Glasgow", "Halifax", "Halifax", "Halifax", "Glasgow") 
ballot_box <- c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
votes <- c(100,100,100,100,100,0,50,3)
df <- data.frame(candidate, city, ballot_box, votes)

df %>% dput() #copy and paste the output

structure(list(candidate = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
"B"), city = c("Halifax", "Halifax", "Halifax", "Glasgow", "Halifax", 
"Halifax", "Halifax", "Glasgow"), ballot_box = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 
1, 2, 3, 4), votes = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 0, 50, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Here is your solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% select(-ballot_box) %>% group_by(candidate, city) %>% summarize(votes = sum(votes))
```

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need the `select` statement, as `summarize` will automatically drop it, since it is not in the `group_by`.